# Is it possible display a banner for ios when receiving push notification while app is in foreground?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Currently my app can receiving push notification and display a banner when receiving a push notification while the app is in background.

But however when my app is in foreground, there is no banner showing up. I look in the log and I found out that I can receive push notification (i print out the payload).

Any way to display a banner while in app? Or is it a limitation?

I am using the Appcelerator Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications for push notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This is not a limitation of Titanium.
- Apple doesn't allow to show notification banner when app is in foreground.
- All you can do is to create and animate a manual view when your Push callback is called in foreground state.

Comment: Ok thanks. 


Another side question, is there any way to read the default notification sound of the phone when using Titanium.Media.createSound? I can be able to pass in a URL for a mp3 or WAV, but I am hoping that I can use what the phone currently is using.

Or is there any other better alternatives besides Titanium.Media.createSound?


EDIT: formatting